# Why is my .gitignore file not ignoring the files I put into it?

Tags: git

This is in my terminal:

```
Changes to be committed:
```

(use "git rm --cached ..." to unstage)

```
new file:   .getignore
new file:   package-lock.json
new file:   package.json
new file:   public/help.html
new file:   server.js
new file:   views/about.hbs
new file:   views/home.hbs
new file:   views/maintenence.hbs
new file:   views/partials/footer.hbs
new file:   views/partials/header.hbs
```

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
node_modules/
server.log
```

tests-MBP:node-web-server brettkessler$

this is my .gitignore file:

```
node_modules/
server.log
```

It seems like it's not picking up on the git ignore file at all. After searching around someone suggested doing this:

```
git rm -r --cached .

git add .

git commit -m "fixing .gitignore"
```

But that doesn't seem to work for me at all.....anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to have misspelled ".gitignore" as ".getignore":

```
new file:   .getignore
```

Try correcting that.

Comment: Well shit haha! Now I feel like a dumbass, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Files that have already been committed will not be 'igonored'.
Please delete the committed file, commit and try again.

Or, if you want to 'igonore' an already committed file, you can do so via the 'update-index' command.
For more information, see here (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index).

Comment: So... you don't think it's a problem to name it .getignore?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I did not see '.getignore'.

Comment: This answer is relevant for when you have correctly named `.gitignore`